# Android: Convert LiveData ArrayList to Gson and back again

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, dao, android-livedata

For my application, I have a recycler view that I'm using LiveData to populate. Each item in the recycler view is an Event object that I created. I'm using Room and Dao to store these Events and to create that abstraction layer between SQL and the repository and UI controller, but the problem is that Dao can only serialize primitize types into JSONs. I created type converters to convert between ArrayList and json, but I need to be able to convert between LiveData[ArrayList[Event]] in order to get this to work.

So far, this is what I have:

```
@TypeConverter
public static String fromEvent(LiveData<ArrayList<Event>> events){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(events);
    return json;
}

@TypeConverter
public static LiveData<ArrayList<Event>> fromEventString (String value){
    Type eventType = new TypeToken<LiveData<ArrayList<Event>>>() {}.getType();
    return new Gson().fromJson(value, eventType);
}
```

How do I interconvert between these two data types using Google's Gson library? Lol I'm obviously not too experienced with this.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer, but I switched from ArrayList to the generic List, and it worked seamlessly. I was reading something about how Gson looks to the superclass of whatever data structure you're using to learn how to serialize and deserialize, so I wondered if switching to: **List[Event] list = new ArrayList()**  instead of **ArrayList[Event] list = new ArrayList()** would do the trick. Indeed, for some reason RoomDatabase knew perfectly how to serialize it this way.